# Four Records on every responsive Row on a ASPX Page

Tags: asp.net, css, c#-4.0

[image: My Page]

My Requirement is to show 4 records in each row there will be more than 7 rows the entire design is responsive so I have to add

```
<div class="row"> 
//Image,lable hyperlink with text
</div>
```

All the records should be dynamic as per the count of DataTable.
I am stuck to add 4 records on

```
<div class="row"> 

</div>
```

On every new line of every row as the responsive work only in the row div.

My Code as if now

```
<div class="row">
    <% foreach (System.Data.DataRow item in dt.Rows)
     {
        %>
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 mix livefeeds">
                    <div class="work-item">
                        <div class="image-holder">
                            <a href="<%=item["Identity"].ToString()%>">
                                <img src="<%=item["ImagePath"].ToString()%>"/>
                                <h4>
                                    <span><%=item["Headline"].ToString()%></span>
                                    </h4>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
         </div>
    <%
    }   
    %>
```

I thaught of adding a if condition like

```
<%
if (dt.Rows.Count %4 ==0)
{
<div class="row">
//Content
</div>
}
%>
```

But getting stuck with the syntax like what to write where and its on a ASPX page.

Comment: You can try using ListView, it has builtin pager for your requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the solution,with the help of bootstrap it will display 4 records on ever single row.

```
    <div class="row" style="margin-left:5px;margin-right:5px">
    <% foreach (System.Data.DataRow item in dt.Rows)
     {  
        %>
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 mix livefeeds News">
                    <div class="work-item">
                        <div class="image-holder">
                            <a href="#">
                                <img src="<%=item["ImagePath"].ToString()%>"/>
                                <h4>
                                    <span><%=item["Headline"].ToString()%></span>
                                </h4>    
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
         </div>
    <%} %>
</div>
```